# HTTP Url handling with IntentFilter

Tags: android, url, android-intent, intentfilter

I've read some other questions about this thread, but no one answered to my question.

My situation is the following: the user cliks on a URL on whatever app (like Facebook, Gmail...), this URL contains `http:\\www.italiansubs.net/forum/...` and some other params. I want the app to handle that specific link, so, following some other questions on the site, I tried this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="italiansubs.net" android:scheme="www" />
    <data android:host="italiansubs.net" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

but everytime I click on URL with that syntax, the Browser shows up and opens the link. I need to incercept that link, then let the app do some other operations, but my app doesn't show as possible pick.

How can I make this code work?

Thanks.

Comment: First, `www` is not a valid scheme, so get rid of that `<data>` element. Second, are you sure the link is for `http://italiansubs.net`, and not `http://www.italiansubs.net`, `https://italiansubs.net`, etc.? Also, bear in mind that it is up to the app how to handle links, and Web browsers usually assume `http`/`https` links should be handled by the browsers themselves. What app(s) were you using for testing the links?

Comment: Ok, my fault, I though that the host was only `italiansubs.net` and not `www.italiansubs.net`. Thanks mate. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `host` value is the full domain name as it appears in the URL. This may mean that you need a few `<data>` elements to handle all combinations of `scheme` (if links might use either `http` or `https`) and `host` (`foo.com`, `www.foo.com`, `wow.subdomains.are.cool.foo.com`, etc.).